# Azure DevOps - Is there any way to get Task ID for tracking log page?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to generate the current step log url. I am able to get other ID's like build id, project id but not the task id(last part integer). I have searched in Azure DevOps Predefined Variables but couldn't get any. Is there any way to get this ID?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variable for this and if you want to construct proper url you have to assume that `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/{logId}?api-version=7.0`

`logId` at the end:

- `1` returns your pipeline definition
- `2` expressions evaluations
- `3` initialize job
- `4` here start your first task from pipeline

But you can use this endpoint to get [all logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-logs?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-logs?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0`